# Selecting conditions dynamically In oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi What I would like to do is take the search criterias as parameters to my function and search through the table depending on the input parameters.. for example: IF ALL the parameters are NULL then the function will return evey field in the table, if a parameter is not NULL that parameter will be a search criteria. I could do an If statement but it would be too long and assuming that I would have had a bigger table it would be very painful, Is there any way I could accomplish this Task? Thanks

My Code:

```
create or replace type ordersinf as object(orderDate DATE, orderName VARCHAR2(20), orderPrice NUMBER)


create or replace type orders_tab IS TABLE OF ordersinf
```

and My Code is:

```
create or replace function execImmFunc(orderDate DATE, orderName in
VARCHAR2, orderPrice in NUMBER) return orders_tab is
  Result orders_tab := orders_tab();
begin

  SELECT  ordersinf(orderDate => orders_Orderdate, orderName => orderName,orderPrice => orders_price)
  BULK COLLECT INTO RESULT
  FROM orders_table
  WHERE  orders_Orderdate >= orderDate OR orders_name = orderName OR orders_price = orderPrice ;

  return(Result);
end execImmFunc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION execImmFunc(
  orderDate  IN DATE,
  orderName  IN VARCHAR2,
  orderPrice IN NUMBER
) RETURN orders_tab
IS
  Result orders_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT  ordersinf(
            orderDate  => orders_OrderDate,
            orderName  => orders_Name,
            orderPrice => orders_price
          )
  BULK COLLECT INTO Result
  FROM   orders_table
  WHERE  ( orderDate  IS NULL OR orders_OrderDate >= orderDate )
  AND    ( orderName  IS NULL OR orders_name = orderName )
  AND    ( orderPrice IS NULL OR orders_price = orderPrice );

  RETURN Result;
END execImmFunc;
```

Comment: Or you can write `orders_name = COALESCE(orderName, orders_name)`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That will work in this case as the OP is testing each condition for equality  (i.e. `=`, `>=` or `<=`) but it won't work in all cases (i.e. when equality is not part of the check - such as `<` or `>`).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean

```
WHERE  (orderDate is null OR orders_Orderdate >= orderDate) AND (orderName is null OR orders_name = orderName) AND (orderPrice  is null OR orders_price = orderPrice );
```

If a parameter orderDate is null - the clause passes and is effectively ignored?

Answer (score 1):

> Hey I dont have workspace with me but below is a very simple snippet
>   which can be used for dynamic sql formation as per the input provided.
>   Hope this helps

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  lv_col1 VARCHAR2(100):=123;
  lv_col2 VARCHAR2(100):=1;
  lv_col3 VARCHAR2(100):=NULL;
  lv_col4 VARCHAR2(100):=45;
  lv_col5 VARCHAR2(100):=8;
  lv_sql LONG;
  lv_where LONG;
BEGIN
  lv_sql:='SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 1 = 1 ';
  SELECT DECODE(lv_col1,NULL,'',' AND col1 = '''
    ||lv_col1
    ||'''')
    || DECODE(lv_col2,NULL,'',' AND col2 = '''
    ||lv_col2
    ||'''')
    || DECODE(lv_col3,NULL,'',' AND col3 = '''
    ||lv_col3
    ||'''')
    || DECODE(lv_col4,NULL,'',' AND col4 = '''
    ||lv_col4
    ||'''')
    || DECODE(lv_col5,NULL,'',' AND col5 = '''
    ||lv_col5
    ||'''')
  INTO lv_where
  FROM dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_sql||lv_where);
END;
```

Comment: This approach can also be implemented in a FUNCTION too as per the question asked.

Comment: While this approach could work, it is inefficient as it does not make use of bind variables so the optimizer is going to have to look at each query separately (since they will all have different hardcoded parameters).

Comment: Bind Variables still possible - [with `USING` keyword for dynamic binding](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BHCHIHEJ). Though the DUAL call is not needed. (Proper)Reconstructing the query will be the best solution always.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: Exactly. Dual call can be avoided and Bind variable is possible anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set up so a parameter is either returned in the resultset or used in the where-clause? It does not look like you do, but rather you want to return all columns and use parameters in where only when they are not null.

If so, why not just a classic nvl-setup?

```
SELECT  ordersinf(orderDate => orders_Orderdate
                 ,orderName => orderName
                 ,orderPrice => orders_price)
  BULK COLLECT INTO RESULT
  FROM orders_table
  WHERE orders_Orderdate >= nvl(orderDate,  orders_Orderdate)
     OR orders_name       = nvl(orderName,  orders_name) 
     OR orders_price      = nvl(orderPrice, orders_price);
```

I imagine those ORs ought to be AND as you probably want all conditions sent in to be true, but that is purely a desugn/requirement issue.